# Is there a way to refresh a childs state from a parent component (Both are function components)

Tags: reactjs

```
function clearChildState(){
  //Stuff to clear child state from parent components
}
```

I want an input from the user (Who sees the parent component) to click a button to clear child components states. How would one go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear child state", would you provide an example.

Comment: I have a shop component with child components that represent items. The item components have their own state to represent how many of them are about to be purchased. I want to click a button in the shop component to set all of the item components values to 0, or refresh them to their default value

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `items` as `prop` (parent->child).

```
<Child items={items} />
```

The child continues to have an `items` state, which is initialized from the `items` prop.
When the parent passes an empty array to the child, the child's `items` state would be reset to `[]`.

This can be achieved using `getDerivedStateFromProps` in class based child component.

```
class Child extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: []};
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state) {
        return {items: props.items};
    }   

    // render
}
```

Comment: I like this answer - I find class based components clearer and easier to work with when you have complicated lifecycle operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use function components, you could use refs and effects to do it like this:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  
  // Store your initial state
  const initialState = {
    name: 'Default Name',
    title: 'Default Title'
  }
  
  const [{name, title} , setState] = React.useState(initialState)
  const setNewState = () => {
    setState({ name: 'New Name', title: 'New Title' })
  }
  
  // Use a ref to store the previous prop value
  const prevClearChildStateCount = React.useRef(0)
  
  // Use effects to run a check whenever the prop is updated
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (props.clearChildStateCount > prevClearChildStateCount.current) {
      setState(initialState)
    }
    prevClearChildStateCount.current = props.clearChildStateCount
  }, [props.clearChildStateCount])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {name}</p>
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <button onClick={setNewState}>Set new state</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [clearChildStateCount, updateClearChildState] = React.useState(0)
  const clearChildState = () => {
    updateClearChildState(clearChildStateCount + 1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent clearChildStateCount={clearChildStateCount} />
      <button onClick={clearChildState}>Clear Child State</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Byron/yxuqe4vg/11/)